# ZF2 set custom URL/route and view

Tags: zend-framework2, request, bootstrapping

I am using ZF2 as a component of another application.

I am looking for a way to set the URL and View Template of the application between an init() and a run() call.  I would like a way to either modify the Request and Response objects, or regenerate them with a different URL.

I currently use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() and a view template that simply generates the_content, thus injecting the output of ZF2 inside a page of another application.

Any suggestions on methodology would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Module.php you can attach event to event manager for exemple.

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager      = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($eventManager, $serviceManager){
            // your code here
        }, -1000);
    }
}
```

Or your action in your controller can dispatch another action and get the result

in action method :

```
$return = $this->forward()->dispatch('controllerName', array('action' => 'actionName', 'param1' => 'value', ...));
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear.  I was hoping to do this while treating the ZF2 as a component (from the outside).  Not necessarily internal to the application.

Comment: More specifically, to find the correct module via a routing and dispatch events from an Application instance.

Answer (score 1):

The following code inside another application can be used to set the calling URL and View Template from outside of the application:

```
$bootstrap = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init( include( '/zf2/config/application.config.php' ) );
$event = $bootstrap->getMvcEvent( );

/* Modify the event with a custom request. */
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request( );
$request->setMethod( \Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_GET );
$request->setUri( $custom_url );
$event->setRequest( $request );

/* Modify the view. */
$event->getViewModel()->setTemplate('layout/custom-layout');

ob_start( );
$bootstrap->run( );
$html = ob_get_clean( );
```

Comment: There is one little problem wit this (otherwise perfectly working) solution: If you statically set `$request->setMethod( \Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_GET );` to "get" you won't be able to use methods like `$request->isPost()` within your controller, e.g when working with forms. So I use: `$request->setMethod( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] );` instead.